# Can't call a custom respository methode symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I've followed every step in the book, but I can't get to work any entity custom repository.
The problem her is that i have been trying to call the method **filtrerExperienceTotal**  but The code completion shortcut (Ctrl-Space) can't find the method, please help

For example, I have my User entity:

```
    <?php

 namespace MTO\CrowdRiseBundle\Controller;
 use MTO\CrowdRiseBundle\Entity\UserRepository;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use MTO\CrowdRiseBundle\Entity\User;

 class ProfilsController extends Controller
 {
 public function filtrerExperienceTotal(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $req = $this->get('request');

    if ($req->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $rechexperienceTot = $req->get('rechexperienceTotname');


        $Users = $em->getRepository('MTOCrowdRiseBundle:User')->filtrerExperienceTotal(0,99);

if (!($Users == null)) {
            return $this->render('MTOCrowdRiseBundle:Profils:profils.html.twig', array('users' => $Users));
        } else {
            return $this->render('MTOCrowdRiseBundle:Profils:profils.html.twig', array('users' => NUll));
        }
    }

    return ($this->redirectToRoute('mto_crowd_rise_profils'));

}
```

*and the repository class*

```
    class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

public function chercherNom($nom){

   $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p')
           ->where('p.nom LIKE :nom')
           ->orWhere('p.prenom LIKE :nom')
           ->orWhere('p.username LIKE :nom')
           ->setParameter('nom', $nom)
           ->getQuery()->getResult();  
  return $qb; 

}
public function filtrerExperienceTotal($experiencemin,$experiencemax){

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p ')
           ->where('p.experienceTot between :parm1 and :param2')
           ->setParameter('param1', $experiencemin)
            ->setParameter('param2', $experiencemax)
           ->getQuery()->getResult();  
  return $qb; 

 }
}
```

*final the user.orm.yml*

MTO\CrowdRiseBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: MTO\CrowdRiseBundle\Entity\UserRepository

```
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    nom:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 40
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    prenom:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 40
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    datenaissance:
        type: date
        nullable: false
        comment: ''
        column: dateNaissance
    situationprof:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
        column: situationProf
    secteur:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    experiencetot:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
        column: experienceTot
    solde:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
        column: solde
    paysnatal:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 40
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
        column: paysNatal
    image:
        type: text
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    role:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    etat:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''
    sexe:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: null
        fixed: false
        comment: ''

lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

please guys i do really need a help

Comment: So the problem is in your IDE autocompletion feature? Not in application/code?

Comment: This does not seem to be symfony problem. Which IDE are you uising?

Comment: i am using netbeans, Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.6.4.zip.
i really don t know what to do :(

Comment: What is getE from `$em->getE`?

Comment: It s something that i deleted laterr but the probleme persist

Comment: i just modified it to i deleted the getE

Comment: Their is something missing in the action. it s the keyword Action, but this doesn t repare the probleme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well at the end, the probleme was from the IDE, all i need it is to force it and write manually the name of the method, it work fine, Thanks alot